# Modify response from CouchDB POST/GET _session

Tags: couchdb

I am storing additional attributes in my '_users' db records. In the case where I have multiple users sharing a database, where one is the owner and one is the reader/writer, I would like to get that user's db property to see what database they have permissions to write to.

Is it possible to modify the response of POST _session or GET _session to respond with the cookie, but also with the db property from a '_users' record in the response body? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible at this time. This idea has been [proposed](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/19362), but not implemented a few reasons. (it's a long thread, but I felt it was relevant)

It sounds like you may want to take advantage of the [database security object](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/security.html#api-db-security). This configuration allows you to set up specific users or roles with read/write capabilities per-database. (plus, this object will be sent to validation function, and it allows custom fields in addition to the mandatory ones)